# How to detect a key pressed for x seconds in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to detect when a user keep press a button for X second and call function in JavaScript. Could you point me out in right direction?

Comment: Just thoughts: in `onKeyDown` handler save the current time, in `onKeyUp` check how much time passed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [a `setTimeout` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) on the `keydown` event which will fire after *X* seconds to compare the time that event was triggered to the last time a `keyup` was triggered - if at all.

```
var lastKeyUpAt = 0;

$(elem).on('keydown', function() {
    // Set key down time to the current time
    var keyDownAt = new Date();

    // Use a timeout with 1000ms (this would be your X variable)
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Compare key down time with key up time
        if (+keyDownAt > +lastKeyUpAt)
            // Key has been held down for x seconds
        else
            // Key has not been held down for x seconds
    }, 1000);
});

$(elem).on('keyup', function() {
    // Set lastKeyUpAt to hold the time the last key up event was fired
    lastKeyUpAt = new Date();
});
```

`elem` here is the element you're wanting to handle the event on.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rj64C/).

Comment: this triggers every `keydown` event after 1000ms, again and again. notice console log spamming: http://jsfiddle.net/Rj64C/3/

Comment: @haxxxton how can this be prevented? I need to fire a function off for both short and long press, but it fires multiple times.

Comment: @MrPablo check out my answer below to prevent the spamming :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the jquery docs, they're super awesome. Something like this could give you the gist, though.

```
var keyTO,
    seconds = 5;
$( "#i" ).on({
  keypress: function(e) {
        if(keyTO) {
            clearTimeout(keyTO);
            keyTO = null;
        }
        keyTO = setTimeout(someFn, seconds*1000);
  },
  keyup: function(e) {
      clearTimeout(keyTO);
      keyTO = null;
  }
});
function someFn() {
    // only called after full timeout
    alert('Sweet.');
}
```

Comment: This fires an event after 5 seconds, it doesn't detect whether the key has been held down... [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3b3bg/).

Answer (score 1):

Watch for [`keydown`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) and [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) events. jQuery's `keydown` event triggers recursively based on the user's keyboard settings for press and hold of keys. You can alternatively set your own recursive checking timeout if you would like to check this more/less frequently or abstract your checking away from varying user's keyboard settings.

This code (thanks to nbrooks for the prompting), monitors each key down event as their own instance, and so will allow for multiple keys to be press and held on a keyboard, each with their own triggertimes.

```
$(function(){
    var keyDownArray = {};
    var triggerTime = 3000; // number of ms to trigger function at

    var keyDownEvent = function(e){
        // use the event keyCode as a unique identifier
        if(!(e.keyCode in keyDownArray) ){
            // use the event keyCode as a unique identifier
            // use setTimeout to make sure trigger only occurs once
            keyDownArray[e.keyCode] = setTimeout(function(){
                // call your function here (can pass in e.keyCode if function requires custom functions on a per key basis)
                console.log('triggered for key '+e.keyCode);
            }, triggerTime);
        }
    }

    var keyUpEvent = function(e){
        // on key release, clearTimeout and delete object key
        clearTimeout(keyDownArray[e.keyCode]);
        delete keyDownArray[e.keyCode];
    };

    $(document).on('keydown', keyDownEvent)
        .on('keyup', keyUpEvent);
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sm998/3/)**

PS. it may be worth adding a throttler (something like [Ben Almans debounce/throttle plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/)) to decrease the potential load of this function

Comment: But wouldn't you want to keep track of the key which was pressed as well? It only counts as holding if the same key which triggered keydown to start the timer is the same on which triggers keyup.

Comment: @nbrooks if a new key is pressed during the initial keydown, a new instance of that keydown is created. ie. "A" pressed, 1 second later "D" is pressed, 1 second later "A" is released (doesnt fire trigger event), 2 seconds later event is fired as "D" is still held down, you can test this in my JS fiddle. it's only if you want specific things to happen based on what the key is that you need to worry about this

Comment: Right, so in that case your `keydowntime` variable doesn't apply exclusively to "D" because it is also counting the original time from "A". Also right now your keyup fires any time a key is released, even if other keys are still down, so it would fire for "A" (also happens in your jsFiddle).

Comment: @nbrooks i see where you're coming from now :) have updated my code to better reflect the potential issue you raised. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/7Z6hg/)

You can accomplish this simply by recording the time at which a key is pressed, and then checking the time again when the key is released. Construct a JS object which maps key-codes to dates.

On keyDown, record the key and current time (if it's not already set—some keys trigger multiple keydowns while being held). On keyUp, find the time difference, clear the map entry, and then process accordingly:

```
$(function () {
    var keyTimes = {};

    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        if (!keyTimes["key" + e.which]) {
            keyTimes["key" + e.which] = new Date().getTime();
        }
    });

    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        if (keyTimes["key" + e.which]) {
            var x = new Date().getTime() - keyTimes["key" + e.which];
            delete keyTimes["key" + e.which];

            // key was held for x/1000.0 seconds
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use keydown() and keyup() to check for the keypress.
Get the current system time with keydown() and compare that with the current system time when you get the keyup().

```
var starttime;
var curKey;

$('#seconds-counter').keydown(function(e) {
  if (curKey != e.which) {
    var d = new Date();
    starttime = d.getTime();
    $('#down-time').text(starttime);
    curKey = e.which;
  }
});

$('#seconds-counter').keyup(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  var endTime = d.getTime();
  $('#up-time').text(endTime);
  var timeTaken = endTime - starttime;
  $('#result-val').text(timeTaken / 1000);
  curKey = null;
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spuggiehawk/8GM28/)

(Edit: forgot the last bit :-) ) Call your function at the end of the keyup(), after curKey = null.